# AngularJS template and audio-element on load

Tags: templates, angularjs

I'm using a template to dynamically load HTML connected to angularJS model with a `ng-repeat`:er. In this template there's an `audio` element. When the template loads Firebug says **"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://mydomain.com/{{test.filename}}**, since it thinks it's an actual path to a audio file. This happens right before the actual audio element is given its proper source.

Is there a way to get around this? It doesn't seem to matter if the model is fetched before or after the template loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to how [ngSrc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSrc) works, you'll need bind the `src` attribute for your `audio` element after your data is available.  I would imagine you can just use `ngSrc` as is (I don't think it's strictly for `img` elements), but you may need to create a custom directive to do this.